# What happens when two global enchantments affect the same type of permanent (e.g.lands)

Tags: magic-the-gathering

At some point in the game, a player puts [Blanket of Night](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlanket%20of%20Night%5d) on the battlefield.
Then,some turns later,another player puts [Blood Moon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlood%20Moon%5d) into play.
If a non-basic land capable of producing mana comes into play, will it be able to produce either red mana or black mana, or just red mana?
And what if the opposite happens?
In other words, if Blood Moon and **then** Blanket of Night come into play, what types of mana will be able to produce a non-basic land instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Non-basic lands will be only mountains. Basic lands are their original type and also swamps.**

Lands are basic if and only if they have the "Basic" type. All other lands are non-basic. Therefore, Blanket of Night does not turn lands into non-basic lands, because it only adds the "swamp" subtype and the "T: Add B" mana ability to lands.

> 205.4c Any land with the supertype “basic” is a basic land. Any land that doesn’t have this supertype is a nonbasic land, even if it has a basic land type.

If a land was basic before, it still is - for example a Forest with types "Basic Land - Forest" is now a "Basic Land - Forest Swamp", with the ability to produce 1 green or 1 black mana.

If a land was a non-basic land, it still is. Blanket again adds the swamp type. For example [Gemstone Mine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGemstone%20Mine%5d) will be a "Land - Swamp", and it will gain the "T: Add B" ability in addition to its printed abilities.

Blood Moon then replaces all of that land's types with "Mountain" and all its abilities with "T: Add R", including the swamp gained by Blanket, so the resulting lands will have the types "Land - Mountain" and the only ability "T: Add R".

Note that for non-basic lands, the order in which you play the Blanket and Blood Moon matters, because of the *layer system*.

> 613. Interaction of Continuous Effects
>
> 613.1d Layer 4: Type-changing effects are applied. These include effects that change an object’s card type, subtype, and/or supertype.
>
> 613.2. Within layers 1–6, apply effects from characteristic-defining abilities first (see rule 604.3), then all other effects in timestamp order (see rule 613.6).

Timestamp order is, generally, the order in which an object or effect entered the game.

If you cast the enchantments in the order you described, Blanket first then Blood Moon, the result will be as described above.

In the reverse order, Blood Moon first turns all non-basic lands into non-basic mountains, then Blanket adds the swamp type and ability to those lands. These lands will then have the types "Land - Mountain Swamp" with respective mana abilities instead of just "Land - Mountain".

Comment: Doesn't rule 613.7 come into play here since I believe (based on your analysis) that  Blanket's effect would be considered dependent on Blood Moon's?  If that's true, Blood Moon's would always apply first, regardless of timestamp.

Comment: My understanding of dependencies is that they don't exist here at all.  Neither ability can change the "text or existence" of the other, and neither can alter what they apply to (Lands and Nonbasic lands...neither effect grants or removes the Land type or the Basic Supertype from any permanents).  Now if we change Blanket to Urborg then we have a dependency on our hands because Blood Moon changes the existence of Urborg's ability.  Likewise, adding Life and Limb would change what the abilities apply to.  But even with a land that doesn't produce mana, I don't see a dependency here.

Comment: @murgatroid99 how would the presence of a non mana-producing land change anything about the situation? Neither card cares about whether lands produce mana or not.

Comment: I think @murgatroid99 mistakenly read the printed text rather than the Oracle text of Blanket of Night

Comment: Well, It is this way, Blanket of Night has a Oracle-changed card text. How it is so really different with the Oracle text.  It must be so also because the Oracle  text of Blood moon speaks only of "mountains", and no longer modifies the non-basic lands in "basic mountains",as it did in the original Dark draft (1995...). Who knows, maybe it was better with the original texts of the cards, I mean not Oracle-modified...anyway, the layer's explanation is very good.

Comment: Why do you rate this question so low? Don't you see how many discussions about clarifications,about "dependency", and about the Oracle modifications of the cards' text? You just like "plain questions" ... stuff easy to untangle really ... ok, soon you'll be satisfied ...!

Comment: @ikegami That's exactly what happened. Checking the Oracle text properly this time, I also do not see a dependency.

Comment: There! Even Murgatroid can make mistakes, sometimes ...!

Comment: I did the opposite and missed the original text.  I agree the original text definitely could cause weird dependency stuff.

Comment: Still I do not understand why, if we do like Gendolkari claims - " Now if we change Blanket to Urborg then we have a dependency on our hands because Blood Moon changes the existence of Urborg's ability. Likewise, adding Life and Limb would change what the abilities apply to". - Why in this situation there is a "Dependency"?? If necessary, let me know this, and I will propose an exact question on this point.

Comment: Urborg, Tomb of Yawgmoth has the same Oracle text as Blanket of Night, but it is a land.  When Blood Moon changes a land to a Mountain, it also loses all other abilities.  As such, Urborg having or not having its ability is dependent on whether Blood Moon has removed it.  So Blood Moon always "wins" and removes the ability from Urborg before it can make any lands into Swamps.  Life and Limb will turn Saprolings into nonbasic Forests, so the ability changes what Blood Moon and Blanket of Night apply to (the Saprolings).  So Life and Limb always has to apply first.

Comment: Oh, I really thank you Caleb. Now I understand. The thing gets me in trouble was that Gendolkari talks about "Urborg" only...when He refers to Urborg,Tomb of Yawgmoth land instead! Yes, it is a land, so Blood Moons wins forever, 'cause his effect affects lands. but....in a case like this last, it is a plain situation....why call it as a "dependency" case? I never did it. probably going on with the game without knowing what dependency situations are.

Comment: Hey, you are mentioning GendoIkari, but I was the one who just mentioned Urborg.  I think I was trying to keep my post under the comment character limit and knew most players would assume which Urborg I was talking about (but not new players, so it was unclear).  Dependencies are extremely rare.  Mostly things just apply by layer (613.1) and timestamp (613.6).  Usually people just remember the common dependency situations for their format rather than figure them out in game (like common interactions with Blood Moon if you play Modern).

Comment: Now I'm wondering why Blanket of Night has that errata... they normally do their best to avoid functional errata except when a rules change requires it... why remove "mana-producing" from Blanket of Night?